# REACT_APP_API_URL is undefined in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, environment-variables

I have added a .env file to my root folder and added the below variable.

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:4000
```

I have used this in a component as below.

```
process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
```

After adding the above, I have restarted the reactJS application and run the application via npm start. I see the below message in the console, but still, the variable gives an undefined value.

> ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000

> info  - Loaded env from D:\ReactJsProj.env

> info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: no next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5

Comment: If you want to access some env variable in the `client side`, you need to `prefix` it with `NEXT_PUBLIC`.

[Next Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser)

Answer (score 2):

it seems you just want to change your port, not the whole app url. so just do this in your `.env` file:

```
PORT=4000
```

and then restart the dev server. it will do the job!

Answer (score 0):

In nextjs you should add env variables in `.env.locale`